# exclude project from solution when running sonar-runner

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have installed and configured SonarQube 3.7.1 and sonar-runner 2.3.

While trying to run sonar-runner on a c# solution I got the error:

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution 
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar 
ERROR: Caused by: Error occured while reading Visual Studio files. 
ERROR: Caused by: Error while processing the project C:\root\MPS\MPA\Main\Source\MPA.Build\MPA.Build.csproj : assemblyName not defined
```

My sonar-project.properties looks like

```
sonar.projectKey=CompanyName:MPA.Android 
sonar.projectName=MPA
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.sources=. 
sonar.language=cs
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
\#sonar.dotnet.key.generation.strategy=safe
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=MPA.sln

sonar.skippedModules=MPA.Build
```

I would like to exclude the project MPA.Build. But it's not working.

In the MPA.sln file the MPA.Build project is defined as

> Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "MPA.Build", "MPA.Build\MPA.Build.csproj", "{A8B400F6-A5C5-4843-96CA-92B25A2E6483}"
>   EndProject

Anyone knows how to solve this error?

when running sonar-runner -X the output is:

> ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
>           at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
>           at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
>           at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
>           at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
>           at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:90)
>           at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
>           at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
>           at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:41) Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Error occured while reading Visual
>   Studio files.
>           at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.core.VisualStudioProjectBuilder.createVisualStudioSolution(VisualStudioProjectBuilder.java:190)
>           at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.core.VisualStudioProjectBuilder.build(VisualStudioProjectBuilder.java:82)
>           at org.sonar.api.batch.bootstrap.ProjectBuilder.build(ProjectBuilder.java:67)
>           at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorReady.start(ProjectReactorReady.java:63)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
>           at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
>           at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
>           at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
>           at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
>           at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
>           at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015)
>           at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008)
>           at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
>           at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
>           at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
>           at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
>           at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
>           at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:82)
>           at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
>           at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
>           at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:156)
>           at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.doAfterStart(BootstrapContainer.java:144)
>           at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
>           at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
>           at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
>           at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
>           at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:45)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
>           ... 9 more Caused by: org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.api.DotNetException: Error while processing
>   the project C:\root\MPS\MPA\Main\Source\MPA.Build\MPA.Build.csproj :
>   assemblyName not defined
>           at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.api.microsoft.ModelFactory.getProject(ModelFactory.java:364)
>           at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.api.microsoft.ModelFactory.getProjects(ModelFactory.java:274)
>           at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.api.microsoft.ModelFactory.getSolution(ModelFactory.java:198)
>           at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.core.VisualStudioProjectBuilder.createVisualStudioSolution(VisualStudioProjectBuilder.java:185)
>           ... 44 more

Answer (score 1):

"assemblyName not defined" => You just have to fix the MPA.Build.csproj file that is not correct because tag "AssemblyName" is missing. See https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/projects/languages/csharp/Example.Core/Example.Core.csproj for example.

Answer (score 0):

The properties file syntax you have appears to be correct.  When you run sonar-runner, you should see lines like this close to the beginning of the run:

```
INFO  - Apply project exclusions 
INFO  - Exclude project: MPA.Build [SomePrefix:MPA.Build]
```

If you don't, I would suggest running sonar-runner with the `-X` argument, which will print debug statements to the console. (You'll likely want to redirect/capture the console to a log file.)  This may present some additional information that could help understand why it's not seeing your exclusion.

Also, in the SonarQube web UI, while looking at the project, click the "Components" link in the left-hand navigation bar.  This will list the "models" for the solution.  Double-check that the name showing in this view matches `MBA.Build`.

Comment: I added the sonar-runner -X output. I don't see the "INFO" output you describe above. Also in the SonarQube web UI, the project is not visible.

Comment: The INFO lines I mentioned would be at the very top of the output, along with other info about how the runner is configured. Can you post the first 20 or so lines of the output when run with -X?

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issu today with sonarqube 5.0.
I tried the "sonar.skippedModules" but this is deprecated now.

Instead, you have to use the following expression provided by the [visual studio bootstraper](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Bootstrapper+for+Visual+Studio+Projects+Plugin) :

sonar.visualstudio.skippedProjectPattern =